# PostgreSQL, Perl, DBD and the Insert command with "TO_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: perl, postgresql, date, insert, timestamp

I'm programming a script which queries some devices and writes the data to a PostgreSQL database.

The data includes a date which is formatted like `31.12.2015 13:45:00`. The database uses the DateType "German" and the column is of the type Timestamp without timezone.

I always get this error message

> DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp:
>   "TO_TIMESTAMP('19.06.2015 11:24:20','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone"
>   at temp_alcp2e_db.pl line 80,  line 289.

I'm using this code, where `$date_db` has the date value:

```
$date_db = 'TO_TIMESTAMP(\'' . $date_db . '\',\'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS\')::timestamp without time zone';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO rifutemp (\"USER_LINK_ID\", \"IP\", \"DATUM\", \"TEMPERATURE\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute($key_bgtr, $key_ip, $date_db, $temperatur) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Hopefully, someone can show me what I did wrong.

Comment: You can not use functions in prepared statement parameters.

Comment: http://snag.gy/drNx6.jpg on pg `9.3.3`

Comment: The PostgreSQL Docs says that the format for german is: "German regional style 17.12.1997 07:37:16.00 PST" so've tried to edit the value into the needed format, which also doesnt work: "DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "19.06.2015 12:02:55.00 PST"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.", any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: which postgres version?.. works for me with 9.3

Comment: @JanAx try siply select, not insert, maybe problem in column type, not the function: select TO_TIMESTAMP('19.06.2015 11:24:20','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone;
    to_timestamp
---------------------
 2015-06-19 11:24:20
(1 row)

Time: 0.292 ms

Answer (score 1):

The function can (and must) be part of the prepared statement.

Re-write your code as follows:

```
$stmt =$dbh->prepare(q{
INSERT INTO rifutemp ("USER_LINK_ID","IP","DATUM","TEMPERATURE")        
        VALUES (?, ?, 
        TO_TIMESTAMP(?, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone,
        ?)
});

$stmt->execute($key_bgtr,$key_ip,$date_db,$temperatur) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found my problem / the source of the errors:

To manage the Database visually I'm using the "EMS SQL Manager Lite for PostgreSQL", and this nice GUI tool always sets the DateStyle options to "ISO, MDY".

I've just changed my code like this:

```
$dbh->do("SET datestyle = 'German'");
$stmt =$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO rifutemp (\"USER_LINK_ID\",\"IP\",\"DATUM\",\"TEMPERATURE\") 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute($key_bgtr,$key_ip,$date_db,$temperatur) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

and set the $date_db variable to the correct format:

```
$date_db = Time::Piece->new->strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S');
```

and now everything works fine!

Comment: If the date format really is `ISO, MDY` then your `strftime` format is wrong. You should use the solution that @user5018637 offers

Comment: You can alter the date format with `ALTER DATABASE dbase SET datestyle TO "German, DMY"`, and I imagine there must be an option in EMS Manager to change this